# mongo_dart error: A value of type 'Rational' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Decimal'

Tags: mongodb, dart

The code below tries to create a Dart server and open a Mongo database. When database section below is commented, then the server starts as expected. Uncommenting the database section dumps the below error on console.

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bson- 
2.0.1/lib/src/types/decimal_128.dart:36:58: Error: A value of type 'Rational' can't 
be assigned to a variable of type 'Decimal'.
```

Environment: MacOS_x64 12.6, Dart SDK version: 2.19.0-264.0.dev (dev)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

// Configure routes.
final _router = Router()
 ..get('/', _rootHandler)
 ..get('/echo/<message>', _echoHandler);

Response _rootHandler(Request req) {
  return Response.ok('Hello, World!\n');
}

Response _echoHandler(Request request) {
  final message = request.params['message'];
  return Response.ok('$message\n');
  }

void main(List<String> args) async {
  // Use any available host or container IP (usually `0.0.0.0`).
  final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;

  // Configure a pipeline that logs requests.
    final handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(_router);

    // For running in containers, we respect the PORT environment variable.
    final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '8080');
    final server = await serve(handler, ip, port);
    print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');

    ///  Database Section  ///
    final db = Db('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb');

    try {
      print('Opening database\n');
      await db.open();
      print('database connected');
      print('Database connected');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      exit(0);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the `bson` package is to blame for the error. I would post an issue ticket on their repository detailing this issue, and also post an issue on the `mongo_dart` package bringing it to their attention. Perhaps they are using an outdated version of the `decimal` or `rational` package. (Or maybe this has already been fixed in the `bson` package and it's the `mongo_dart` package that needs to update its dependencies.)

[Per the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/decimal/latest/decimal/Decimal/pow.html), `Decimal.pow` returns a [`Rational`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rational/latest/rational/Rational-class.html), and `Decimal` and `Rational` are not directly compatible types. They would need to use the extension method [`Rational.toDecimal`](https://pub.dev/documentation/decimal/latest/decimal/RationalExt/toDecimal.html) to convert the value back to a `Decimal`.

```dart
// For example
final Decimal maxUint64 = Decimal(2).pow(64).toDecimal();
```

Comment: I was using mongo_dart 0.8.0-1.0 beta.
Using 0.7.4+1 now and it works!